# Strange definition of topology relying on strange claims...

Tags: general-topology

I am brushing up my knowledge of topology, and I started from the very beginning—the definition of topology. I'm using a book called 'Elementary general topology' by Theral O. Moore, and the definition given is the following:

**Definition 1.1** Lex *X* be a set. A collection $\mathcal{T}$ of subsets of *X* is called a *topology for X* iff

1. the union of *each* subcollection of $\mathcal{T}$ is a member of $\mathcal{T}$ and
2. the intersection of *each finite* subcollection of $\mathcal{T}$ is a member of $\mathcal{T}$

It is left as an exercise to show that $\varnothing, X \in \mathcal{T}$, which I find odd, since this is generally *required* in the definition of topology. I can easily see how $\varnothing \in \mathcal{T}$ follows from the given definition, because we can take an empty subcollection of $\mathcal{T}$ whose empty union will by definition be in $\mathcal{T}$, but the proof that $X \in \mathcal{T}$ relies on a claim whose logic I kind of follow, but find quite sketchy.

The sketchy claim is that if $\mathcal{C}$ is an empty collection of subsets of $X$, then $\cap \mathcal{C} = X$. From this claim and part 2 of definition 1.1 it does follow that $X \in \mathcal{T}$, but what he's saying here is that if you take the intersection over an empty collection, you obtain the whole space. The proof of this claim goes like this:

Suppose $p\in X$. Then, since $\mathcal{C}$ is null, it is correct that $p$ belongs to every member of $\mathcal{C}$. Hence $p \in \cap \mathcal{C}$ and so $X \subset \cap\mathcal{C}$. But since $\cap\mathcal{C} \subset X$, then $X = \cap\mathcal{C}$.

Now, I understand that in an empty collection of subsets of $X$ there *is* no subset that doesn't contain $p$, but there isn't one that contains it either, and I'm not sure this logical subtlety is enough to justify the conclusion. If it were, I don't see why this wouldn't work with unions as well: I could take an empty collection $\mathcal{E}$ of subsets of *X*, and since there is no element of $\mathcal{E}$ that does *not* contain *X*, conclude that $\cup\mathcal{E}=X$.

As a matter of fact, I think I have a counterexample to the fact that $X\in \mathcal{T}$ would follow from definition 1.1.

Let $X = \lbrace a, b \rbrace.$ Define $\mathcal{T}=\lbrace \varnothing, \lbrace a \rbrace \rbrace$. The union and intersection of any subcollections of $\mathcal{T}$ are still in $\mathcal{T}$, so $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology according to definition 1.1, even though $X \not\in \mathcal{T}$.

I refuse to belive a math professor would get wrong such a basic concept, get it published in a book, and nobody even ever noticed, so please, can you show me where I am wrong? :)

Comment: You could interpret it very much the same way you do $\sum \emptyset = 0$ or $\prod \emptyset = 1$, just assign $\cap \emptyset$ the desired meaning.

Comment: I think you are right here.

Comment: @par, what do you think of my counterexample? If it is right, then the book's proof can't be right.

Comment: Your counterexample is fine, but I really do think that in this case the author is adopting the convention $\cap \emptyset=X$ (in which case $X$ would be in $\mathcal{T}$). As for one of your other concerns, note that the "natural" definition of the union of an empty family is $\cup \emptyset = \emptyset$. I wouldn't worry about this too much; I would just take whatever definition of topology you are comfortable with and go forth.

Comment: @par Thanks, now I see! My counterexample is fine if I adopt the convention $\cap \varnothing = \varnothing$; however, if I accept the convention $\cap \varnothing= X$, then $\mathcal{T}$ in my counterexample isn't a topology because $X$—the intersection of an empty subcollection of $\mathcal{T}$—isn't there. Right?

Comment: That is correct! (+1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the author is adopting the convention $\cap \emptyset = X$. In this case, the counterexample is not a topology because it lacks the set $X$. However, without this convention, the counterexample is a topology (under the "broken" definition).

Answer (score 1):

Given a set of subsets {${A_i}$} of $X$ indexed by $I$, where $A \subseteq X$ is the intersection of all $A_i$, $$x \in A \iff \forall i\in I,  \space x\in A_i$$
If $I = \emptyset$, this is (vacuously) true for all $x$ in $X$, and so $A = X$.